# An algorithm to determine a subset sequence in O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, sum, sequence, induction

How can i aproach this problem by induction?

Suppose that you are given an algorithm as a black box you cannot see how it is designed it has the following properties: if you input any sequence of real numbers and an integer k, the algorithm will answer YES or NO indicating whether there is a subset of numbers whose sum is exactly k. Show how to use this black box to find the subset of a given sequence {X1, …., Xn} whose sum is k. You can use the black box O(n) times.

Any idea?

Comment: So the problem is to show how to use the black box to find the starting index of such a subset in a sequence of numbers?

Comment: The problem is about using induction with dynamic programming...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely convinced that induction is necessary here.

Here's my two cents:

Suppose you have a sequence of numbers `S`, and integer `k`, and you already know that there exists a subset of numbers whose sum is `k`. Now, remove a number from your sequence (call it `i`), and use your black box on what remains (using the same `k` as before).

- If the algorithm returns YES on the new sequence, what does that tell you about `i` and any subset of `S` whose sum is `k`?
- If the algorithm returns NO on the new sequence, what does that tell you about `i` and any subset of `S` whose sum is `k`?

Comment: This is the way to go. +1 for not explicitly answering a homework question.